# Server error when sending mail via jsp

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, email

I've a button on my application that has to check if inputted data is correct, adds it to a database and sends an email, it's represented by the following code:

```
<%@ page import = "java.text.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*, javax.mail.Service"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>

[...]

<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="      
javascript:if(confirmaEnviar())$('#usuario').submit();
 <% String result;
// Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String to = "existingdirection@gmail.com";
    String from = "existingdirection2@gmail.com";
    String subject = "test";
    String messageText = "body test";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.host", host);
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    // If using authentication, otherwise comment out
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    // Gmail requires TLS, your server may not
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(messageText);

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

    //connect with authentication
    transport.connect(host,"existingdirection2@gmail.com" , "password");


    transport.sendMessage(msg, address);

    transport.close();

 %>                                 
return false;" class="button button-alt">ENVIAR</a></div>
```

But if I upload it and try to execute it I get an error in the browser: Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

I had thought that it might be that jsp code couldn't be called that way (in the middle of an onclick) but if I put it into another place of the code (in the middle of html tags) the error still reproduces.

I've added the library for java mail to the java build path and I've also copied it to the lib directory.

Of course it has been tested that what fails is the email related code, if I delete it from the application the rest goes nicely.

Email directions of passwords have also been checked to be correct.

I'm using GAE to host the application.

Any idea of what might be happening?

I'm grateful for your help.

Edit: That's the stack trace, guess it's not really a code related question after all..

com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console. at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1567) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:259) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:68) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:202) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:199) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:199) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:68) at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:107) at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:56) at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.apiProxyMakeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:90) at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:58) at com.google.appengine.api.socket.NameServiceImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(NameServiceImpl.java:61)

Strnage thing is that there's no API called Socket API in Google Api's console, guess I'll also try to contact a google consultor also.

Comment: do you have any stacktrace for us???

Comment: I'm putting it now, I forgot sorry.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace, otherwise it's almost impossible to help you.

Comment: It's posted at the end, anyway as I've edited it doesn't look to be a code related error, but help is apreciated anyway, I just don't see any google api that's called socket API on its console.

Comment: Is `existingdirection2@gmail.com` an administrator for your app? Only administrator email addresses are allowed to send mail. Se [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail)

Answer (score 0):

GAE comes with it's own SMTP server, so you do not need to set your own SMTP parameters: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail

However, if you do set your own SMTP parameters then GAE will use sockets which have this [limitations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/). These apply in your case:

1. Sockets are available only for paid apps - **this is the one producing Error**.
2. Port 25 (SMTP) is blocked
3. Google IP ranges are blocked, except Gmail SMTPS: smtp.gmail.com port 465 and 587